# select multiple rows in bokeh datatable

Tags: jquery, python-2.7, datatable, bokeh

Is it possible to make a datatable in Bokeh in which you can select multiple rows without hitting shift/ctrl.

I would like to do the following:

1. Select rows on the datatable by clicking on them.
2. Selecting additional rows doesn't remove the previous ones I selected.
3. Clicking again on a selected row unselects it.

Is this at all possible?  According to the documentation:

http://docs.bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html

if you pass Enum('checkbox') to selectable, you can select multiple rows, but I haven't had any luck.  I keep getting the following error:

ValueError: expected an element of either Bool or Enum('checkbox'), got

If it is possible to use Enum('checkbox') to solve my problem, can anyone send along a line of code that shows how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

With `bokeh==1.3.4` this invocation is working for me to enable the checkbox feature

```
DataTable(
    source=sequence_description_source,
    columns=columns,
    editable=False,
    reorderable=True,
    scroll_to_selection=True,
    sortable=True,
    selectable="checkbox",
)
```